# Cast process.env to <any> with TS

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have a couple logging statements like so:

```
log.info('docker.r2g run routine is waiting for exit signal from the user. The container id is:', chalk.bold(process.env.r2g_container_id));
log.info('to inspect the container, use:', chalk.bold(`docker exec -it ${process.env.r2g_container_id} /bin/bash`));
log.info('to stop/kill the container, use kill, not stop:', chalk.bold(`docker kill ${process.env.r2g_container_id}`));
```

when I transpile this with `tsc`, I get these errors:

```
src/commands/run/run.ts(132,94): error TS2339: Property 'r2g_container_id' does not exist on type 'ProcessEnv'.

133 log.info('to stop/kill the container, use kill, not stop:', chalk.bold(`docker kill ${process.env.r2g_container_id}`));
```

what is the best way to cast `process.env` to `any` or whatnot, to get rid of these errors? Or perhaps I can extend ProcessEnv to include the env variables I am looking for? The former seems fine though.

I tried this:

```
declare global {

  namespace NodeJS {
    export interface ProcessEnv {
      r2g_container_id: string,
      docker_r2g_is_debug: string
    }
  }

}
```

but that's not quite right.

Here is a similar question we might defer to: [using process.env in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194598/using-process-env-in-typescript?rq=1)

Comment: The same way as with `window`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript

Comment: here is the most similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194598/using-process-env-in-typescript?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work too:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface EnvironmentVariables {
    r2g_container_id: string,
    docker_r2g_is_debug: string
  }
}
```

Found here:
https://github.com/typings/registry/issues/770

Answer (score 1):

```
(<any>process.env).r2g_container_id
```

This should be enough to cast to type `any`

Comment: and I believe you can alias to it also if you don't want to cast it multiple places in your file, e.g. `const env = <any>process.env`

Comment: upvoted, but not really what I am looking for tbh because that's a lot of manual calls I don't want to make.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work:

```
declare global {

  namespace NodeJS {

    export interface ProcessEnv  {
      [key:string]: string,
      r2g_container_id: string,
      docker_r2g_is_debug: string,
      docker_r2g_fs_map: string
      HOME: string
    }

  }

}
```

I am not sure if that augments or overrides the existing definition, but in any case the compilation errors are gone.