# typescript error - cannot find name 'process'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am setting up a new project with express+ typescript and facing typescript error - cann't find name 'processs'[image]

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7",
    "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.10",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript-eslint-parser": "^21.0.1"
  }
```

I tried to follow the [solution](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/93)  and added types
tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "types": ["node"] -----
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

But I still get the error. I have installed npm (6.4.1) and node (8.14.0) to start building up my new project. Can someone highlight what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Your new configuration looks right. Although, you probably have to restart typescript language server if it still uses previous version of the tsconfig. In order to do this in VS Code, you do `Ctrl+Shift+P` and `Reload Window` or `TypeScript: Restart TS server` if available.

Also you don't need `tsc` package in your dependencies, because it is deprecated now, and `typescript` package comes with `tsc` executable.

Comment: Just to point out that it's the `@types/node` dev dependency that seems to be required to fix this issue. At least, that's what got rid of the error for me.

Comment: You may also need a tsconfig.json file https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I did `yarn add -D @types/node`, then I restarted the TS server, and now it works. I don't have a `tsconfig.json`, using Node.js v18.9.0

Answer (score 102):

Make sure you have `"types": ["node"]` in your `tsconfig.app.json` file. Having it in `tsconfig.json` was not enough for me (Angular 12).

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["node"]
  },
 ...
}
```

Comment: This helped me with Vue 3 + Vite.

Answer (score 37):

> Just to point out that it's the @types/node dev dependency that seems to be required to fix this issue. At least, that's what got rid of the error for me. – devklick Jul 8 at 8:42

Using npm:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/node
```

Using Yarn: ([@netotz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10308289/netotz))

```
yarn add -D @types/node
```

Comment: Following this yielded ```npm ERR! 404  '@typescript-eslint/type-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint/types-utils/-/types-utils-5.19.0.tgz' is not in the npm registry.```

Comment: `yarn add -D @types/node`

Answer (score 7):

I got the error in `/test/*.spec.ts` files only.

I didn't want to add `@types/node` to my main dependencies.

For me, updating my `tsconfig.json` as follows fixed it:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I had a similar issue, that the --save-dev didnt work, so I would say add the @types/node as a normal dependency instead of a dev one.

[image]

Comment: You don't need types as dependency because you only use it while developing hence why it's in devDependencies.

Comment: @A1rPun but this indeed fixed my problem too. It works when I run it, but for some reason, VS Code type errors unless the types are not in dependencies.

Comment: @GolDDranks I think that worked for you as when we are adding on dependecies we can do npm install, and this will be installed on node_modules, if the type isn't on node_modules would be hard to use them.

I would say if you want to add as devDependecies you also need to install:

npm install --only=dev

I think after this you will be able to make it work as devDependecy.

I hope this helps!