# Environment variable with dotenv and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, dotenv

I create this `.env` file:

```
TYPE=xxx
HOST=xxx,
PORT=xxx,
USERNAME=xxx,
PASSWORD=xxx,
DATABASE=xxx,
```

in my file I use in this way:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    port: process.env.PORT
}
```

but i can use only my `port` variable from `.env` file and i cannot use rest of the variables,
can someone tell me why i can't use rest of my vars?

Comment: What do you mean by, you cant use them? Are they undefined or throwing some kind of error.

Comment: undefined all of them

Comment: You have to export typeOrmConfig as a function not json, otherwise at run time it would be undefined. The values are assigned during compile time.
(Look at solution below).

Answer (score 119):

Actually you have define the path of the .env file

Try like this

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname+'/.env' });
```

Try this also

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname+'/.env' });
```

> Change the path of .env file as required

reference : https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#options

Comment: Finally, Hero at last!

Comment: Just what I was looking for... 

Answer (score 39):

If you get undefined value and if you use ES6, you need to import it as follows (.env file must be in project root directory) :

How do I use dotenv with import?

> 1. Preload dotenv: node --require dotenv/config index.js (Note: you do not need to import dotenv with this approach)
> 2. **Import dotenv/config instead of dotenv (Note: you do not need to call dotenv.config() and must pass options via the command line or
>    environment variables with this approach)**
> 3. Create a separate file that will execute config first as outlined in this comment on #133

You have to import in your project's app.ts file (first)
Example with express:

app.ts

```
//here
import 'dotenv/config'

import express from 'express'
import { userRouter } from './routes/user'

const app = express()

app.use(`/users`, userRouter)
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`running`)
})
```

Now use it anywhere in your project

It is always good to [read the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: Good approach Diego.To make your example more visible, switch the port 4000 to some variable (process.env.PORT for instance). It would help others to understand what happens after the `import dotenv/config`.

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

My project has `eslint` setup, so I have to disable the `import/first` rule

```
/* eslint-disable import/first */
require('dotenv').config();

import Koa from 'koa';

import { Logger } from './utils/loggers';
import { app } from './app';

const LOGGER = Logger();
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10) || 8081;

const server = (server: Koa) => {
  server.listen(port, () => {
    LOGGER.info(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
};

server(app());
```

We can also use:

```
import 'dotenv/config'
```

but

```
require('dotenv').config({path:path_to_dotenv});
```

is more flexiable.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a React app and you are using react-script you need to prefix the key with REACT_APP_ otherwise they will be ignored.

```
REACT_APP_TYPE=xxx
REACT_APP_HOST=xxx
REACT_APP_PORT=xxx
REACT_APP_USERNAME=xxx
REACT_APP_PASSWORD=xxx
REACT_APP_DATABASE=xxx
```

Ref -> https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: I don't know why did you get minus points only... after hours of research, your comment saved my day ...

Comment: This has helped me out and saved hours. Nice catch!

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki down-votes were likely because OP was asking about a NestJS app, not a React app

Answer (score 3):

You could use built-in NestJs way to handle this (ConfigModule).

[Configuration | NestJs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)

```js
// main.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { InventoriesModule } from './inventories/inventories.module';
import typeORMConfig from './config/database.config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { PrismaModule } from './prisma/prisma.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(), // load .env file
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeORMConfig()),
    InventoriesModule,
    PrismaModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
// ./config/database.config

import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export default function (): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
        'type': 'mysql',
        'host': process.env.DB_HOST,
        'port': 3306,
        'username': process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        'password': process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        'database': process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        'entities': ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        'synchronize': false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me...

```
import "dotenv/config";
```

If this doesn't work you can use this

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, just simply..

```
import 'dotenv/config' // see https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import
// other library import
```

Notice that, dotenv import should first rather than other library that use .env variable.

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

Answer (score 0):

This is Nestjs way how to set environment variables:

```
 npm install @nestjs/config
```

That packages internally uses `dotenv` package which puts together all environment variables in your machine.

**app.module.ts**

```
// configModule chooses the .env file, configservice extract the settings
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';


@Module({
  imports: [
    // list your project's modules
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      // this is set so we do not have to reimport the ConfigModule all over the place into other modules
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    // Notice we are not using TypeOrmModule.forRoot({})
    // we set this to get access to ConfigService through dependency injection system
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      // this tell DI system, find the configService which has all of the config info
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          type: 'sqlite',
          database: config.get<string>('DATABASE'),
          synchronize: true,
          entities: [User, Report],
        };
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, it was driving me nuts until I realized I copied pasted environment values from a YAML file which does not have **the same format than the .env file**.

One uses `:`, the other uses `=`.

If it helps another developer soul :-)

Comment: what is the difference between the two formats ?

Comment: @Jyotirmoy one is a YAML format (used in config files) and uses : while the other one is an environment config file that is able to be processed by Unix Shells as it is for example and uses the assignment operator =

Comment: so can we use both interchangeably or do we have use cases for certain scenarios ?

Comment: @Jyotirmoy The YAML format which uses `:` is used in config files (for example using dotenv for NodeJs but you also see it in Kubernetes config files). The other format is a Unix shell script that uses `=`, it sets environment variables when you execute a script file in this format from a compatible shell (let's say Bash).

Answer (score 0):

//Try using like below, it will read all varaibles from .env

import * as dotenv from "dotenv"

dotenv.config();

Answer (score 0):

For relative paths you can use this:

```
import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const envPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.env');
dotenv.config({ path: envPath });
```

assuming .env file is found at parent directory. `../.env`

Answer (score 0):

If you using REACT+typeScript on Front, by convention, you need use REACT_APP in your name variable, like this.

```
REACT_APP_NAMEOFVARIABLE = "Name of Variable"
```

And to use, u will use normaly. You can creates a variable or do a direct acces, like this:

```
const variableName = process.env.REACT_APP_NAMEOFVARIABLE

console.log(variableNAme)
```

Or like this (direct way)

```
<a> ${process.env.REACT_APP_NAMEOFVARIABLE}</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must import the dotenv and execute dotenv.config() at the top most of root file.

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.
> Ref:[dotenv-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score -1):

I got this problem and here is my solution

- Install both `@types/dotenv-webpack` and `dotenv-webpack`

```bash
npm i -D @types/dotenv-webpack dotenv-webpack
```

- And follow the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)