# Typescript says NextJS environment variables are undefined

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, react-google-login

I'm trying to make social login using 'react-google-login'.

.env in root

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=askfjaskf
```

Ready.tsx

```
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
<GoogleLogin
    clientId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
    render={(props) => (
      <div onClick={props.onClick}>
        <div>구글 로그인</div>
      </div>
    )}
    onSuccess={(res) => {
      const { profileObj } = res as any;
      setStep(AuthStep.AGREE);
    }}
    onFailure={(res) => {
      console.log("Google Error", res);
    }}
  />
```

And in clientId, it says

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: GoogleLoginProps | Readonly): GoogleLogin', gave the following error.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: GoogleLoginProps, context: any): GoogleLogin', gave the following error.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
> index.d.ts(80, 12): The expected type comes from property 'clientId' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>'

I don't know why it says it can be undefined.
And it works on local but it doesn't work in production deployment. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue but with different ENV variable, the issue is typescript doesn't know if an ENV variable exists or not.

Check this other question:
[using process.env in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194598/using-process-env-in-typescript)

It helped me fixing this problem. Just need to create the `environment.d.ts` and declare the global ENV variables as the type you want them to be

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: string; // this is the line you want
      NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
      PORT?: string;
      PWD: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The answer with `declare global { ...` didn't work out for me.

The recommanded approach is to create a type declaration file, for example `env.d.ts` with the following declaration:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    JWT_TOKEN: string;
  }
}
```

And then add this reference in your `tsconfig.json` file's `include`:

```json
{
    "include": [
        "next-env.d.ts",
        "env.d.ts",
    ]
}
```

**Discouraged approach**

Do not add a reference in `next-end.d.ts`, Next.js [docs mention](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#existing-projects) that:

> A file named next-env.d.ts will be created at the root of your project [...] You should not remove it or edit it as it can change at any time.

Instead, please use a recommended approach:

> Instead of editing next-env.d.ts, you can include additional types by adding a new file e.g. additional.d.ts and then referencing it in the include array in your tsconfig.json.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't need to add the reference to the new file in `next-env.d.ts`. I made the file named `environmnt.d.td` and vs code picked it up automatically.

Comment: The Next.js docs mention not edit the `next-env.d.ts` directly. Instead, create a separate filename.d.ts file and then add it in your `tsconfig.json` under `include` property - [Nextjs doc link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#existing-projects)

Comment: I couldn't find anything about environment variables in [the linked next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#existing-projects). Probably they have changed ? Is there another place where this is documented ?

Answer (score 6):

**you need to cast it to a string**

```
export default NextAuth({
providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
    }),
]})
```