# Extending process.env variable types in Nodejs with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

So, I have a logic that sets different baseURLs depending on the NODE_ENV that I am in.

My problem is that `process.env.NODE_ENV` has only two types, `development` and `production` and I also want to have the option for `staging`.

So what I have tried to do is create a file called `environment.d.ts` at the root folder of my project, and inside I did:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv {
    NODE_ENV: "development" | "production" | "staging";
  }
}
```

However I am still getting the error when trying to use `staging`:

`This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"production"' and '"staging"' have no overlap.ts(2367)`

```
export const baseURL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost:3000"
    : process.env.NODE_ENV === "staging"
    ? `https://ego-stage.herokuapp.com/`
    : process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? "https://egolounge.com/"
    : "http://localhost:3000";
```

The line that's giving me the error is the line where I am comparing if `NODE_ENV` is equal to `staging`, since `staging` as a type is not present in the default interface for `NODE_ENV`, so I need to extend it with my own definition, however the definition that I created does not supersede for some reason the default one, and when I push to the server, its not building.

Comment: Does it really matter what they are in these case? Instead of saying `string` I am being explicit about the strings that I want as values, this is irrelevant to the problem...

Comment: You're asking a technical question: getting your terms right _always_ matters.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is Typescript, not Javascript, and this is an `interface` not a class, or a function, there is no logical `||` operator here.

Comment: That is how the interface should be, the code is correct (in terms of that logic), the problem is that the definition I created does not get recognized and does not superseed the default type for `process.env.NODE_ENV` which is only `"staging" | "production"` and just to make my point about that even more clear, here is the default interface built into the node types: https://prnt.sc/4WWMhoIV4CIR if I add `| "staging"` here it works just fine, but thats located in `node_modules` so it does not get pushed to the server, thats why I need to extend it.

Comment: Fair enough, but: [don't put pictures of code in your post](/help/how-to-ask), put the text in  your code. Especially as the TS error is getting flagged for code you're not showing right now.

Comment: What do you use these urls for ? Just a small check, if you want to use this code in the frontend in the browser, this solution will never work. If it is for backend, then maybe you only need 2 options development or prod, and for prod another env variable, that you can set at runtime, so you don't need to rebuild your app ?

Comment: It looks like you want to use a different name for that interface, if [using process.env in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194598/using-process-env-in-typescript) is to be believed. At least two of the answers there sound like they solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do exactly what you wanted using a different file name and dropping any exports.

```
// <project_root>/index.d.ts
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
     NODE_ENV: 'dev' | 'stg' | 'prod';
  }
}
```

I just shorthand the accepted values for NODE_ENV, since I just wanted to extend the interface with other values I have in my .env file.

I found the `export interface` did nothing extra to extend the ProcesEnv interface.

I think if you want to change the name of the file, you'll still have to include the `index.d.ts` and ref with an import (or that weired tripple slash).

Or you'll need to add it to the includes in your tsconfig.json file.
Someone wanna fact check me on that?