# How to remove TS2345 errors in electron-main.ts file created by Quasar CLI in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, electron, webstorm, quasar

This is my WebStorm editor screen:

[image]

Here, WebStorm marks `QUASAR_ELECTRON_RELOAD` and `APP_URL` with the red underline and displays  `TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'` and `QUASAR_ELECTRON_PRELOAD is undefined` or `APP_URL is undefined` when hovering on.

I've tried to add `env.d.ts` file on the same directory as `electron-main.ts` with the following contents, but the error still shows.

```js
/* eslint-disable */

declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
        QUASAR_ELECTRON_PRELOAD: string;
        APP_URL: string;
    }
}
```

How can I remove the errors?

---

**UPDATE**

Adding the following contents to the `electron-main.ts` solved the problem.
(BTW, ESLint complains on using `namespace` with this message: `ESLint: ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces.(@typescript-eslint/no-namespace)`)

```js
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv {
            QUASAR_ELECTRON_PRELOAD: string;
            APP_URL: string;
        }
    }
}
```

But, changing `env.d.ts` file's content as the following did not solve the problem.

```
/* eslint-disable */

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv {
            QUASAR_ELECTRON_PRELOAD: string;
            APP_URL: string;
        }
    }
}

export {};
```

Maybe WebStorm does not refer the other module file when checking a file's error?

Comment: Can you check the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45194598/8613630)? try to add `declare global`

Comment: @TobiasS. Thank you! Please see my UPDATE on the question. But I had to apply the answer somewhat differently. I don't know why...