# Typescript class does not recognize constants in .env file, but recognizes them in a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables

I am using .env file and reading from it.
I use it like this: `process.env.BASE_URL` in both the class and the react component.
Why would it work in the component and in the class it is undefined?

This is the class and here the value of `process.env.BASE_URL` is undefined:

```
export default class HttpClient {
  async prepareFileForSigning(file: string) {
    var request = {
      data: file,
    };

    const res = await axios
      .post<GetAttachmentsResponse, AxiosResponse<any>>(process.env.BASE_URL + "/something", request)
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data.info);
        NotificationManager.error(
          err.response.data.info ?? t("notifications.serverError"),
          t("notifications.error"),
          3000
        );
      });
    return (res as any).data;
  }
}
```

This is the React component and here the value of `process.env.CLIENT_ID` and the rest is good:

```
export const ChooseSign: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {

        var request = {
          client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
          scope: process.env.SCOPE,
          grant_type: process.env.GRANT_TYPE,
          requested_token_use: process.env.REQUESTED_TOKEN_USE,
          assertion: res,
        };

        //rest of the code
};

export default ChooseSign;
```

This is my .env file:

```
# prod
# CLIENT_ID=############
# CLIENT_SECRET=############
# CONSENT_URL=############
# dev
CLIENT_ID=############
CLIENT_SECRET=############
CONSENT_URL=############
#
SCOPE=user.read contacts.read mail.read email offline_access openid profile
GRANT_TYPE=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
REQUESTED_TOKEN_USE=on_behalf_of
#
BASE_URL=############
BASE_URL_GRAPH=############
BASE_URL_MICROSOFT_ONLINE=############
#
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3007
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either define a default value for the environment variable in the URL:

```
const res = await axios
      .post<GetAttachmentsResponse, AxiosResponse<any>>((process.env.BASE_URL || "default URL") + "/something", request)
```

Or define environment variable types in an `environment.d.ts` file, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981706) answer for more.

The values in `ChooseSign` are good because you are defining a new object, so the string values can be of type `string | undefined`.
On the other hand, the `axios` call requires a `string`.