# Can I convert a { [key: string]: string | undefined }-like type into { [key: string]: string } type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using `dotenv` for ENV variables. To make autosuggestions work, I'm using

```
const {
    SECRET1,
    SECRET2,
    ...
} = process.env
const secrets = {
    SECRET1,
    SECRET2,
    ...
} as const satisfies { [key: string]: string | undefined }

type secretKey = keyof typeof secrets

for(const key in secrets) if(!secrets[key as secretKey]) throw new Error(`Expected ${key} to be set in .env`)
```

after this point, all secrets should be set (otherwise, the app throws and goes down), but `secrets` is still of type

```
{
    readonly SECRET1: string | undefined;
    readonly SECRET2: string | undefined;
    ...
}
```

I'd like to cast it to

```
{
    readonly SECRET1: string;
    readonly SECRET2: string;
    ...
}
```

but keep it DRY. I've tried

```
const checkedSecrets = secrets as Required<typeof secrets>
```

but that doesn't help (`checkedSecrets` still has those "undefined" as `SECRET1` is not *optional*, it is `string | undefined` instead – I guess `Required` doesn't help with that). I've checked Utility Types, but haven't found a solution there. Could you suggest one?

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked per se but you might want to use typescript declarations to get autocompletions in a more typescripty way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981706/6707985

Answer (score 1):

You can construct mapped type and use `Exclude` to remove `undefined` from each property.

```js
type secretsType = typeof secrets;
type secretKey = keyof secretsType
const checkedSecrets = secrets as { readonly [KEY in secretKey]: Exclude<secretsType[KEY], undefined>; }
```

that will give you:

```js
const checkedSecrets: {
    readonly SECRET1: string;
    readonly SECRET2: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By defining the environment variables as string literals, you can both validate their presence and the desired type at once:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-P5reEK6AhiJcUEwUiESDJMNkQKprgsqHQACOhCt0BweRSADUHWV4R16ABlHIAYQOOQAKgB9ACM9GuLfbnd7ACZ6GtkWCki1okX-cgMw3UulKJlstXejAyxWq-k65AJMGmexgAA9XZpsAAeQOYzTRZBg1bHe7-dmgxAl9Br9HPbHT8zx-F8R3fABma5gAAKlAbVdTJadgmOM05lBAA-TCsMw0EAAUeT0NwmgAcj-CDiNAepJHQDB3FkShISSUBtD0UBiNRV5wGHN9ewHUAAB8PDI8dBzxZYCWIgVejHcDwIATgZaDgC4RFEzXDdcnybdS3LGB91resTyAA)

```ts
function validateEnv<Keys extends readonly string[]>(
  keys: Keys,
): string[] extends Keys ? Record<never, never> : Record<Keys[number], string> {
  const result = {} as Record<Keys[number], string>;

  for (const key of keys) {
    const value = process.env[key];
    if (!value) throw new Error(`Expected environment variable "${key}" not set`);
    result[key as Keys[number]] = value;
  }

  return result;
}

const requiredEnvVars = ["SECRET_1", "SECRET_2"] as const;

const secrets = validateEnv(requiredEnvVars);
    //^? const secrets: Record<"SECRET_1" | "SECRET_2", string>

// OR:

const {
  SECRET_1,
  //^? const SECRET_1: string
  SECRET_2,
  //^? const SECRET_2: string
  SECRET_3, /* Error (as expected)
  ~~~~~~~~
  Property 'SECRET_3' does not exist on type 'Record<"SECRET_1" | "SECRET_2", string>'.(2339) */
} = validateEnv(requiredEnvVars);
```

As you can see in the code above, the return type of the function is an object having only keys that correspond to the string literals and `string` values at those keys. Attempting to destructure other keys will cause a compiler error.

---

The one minor annoyance of this technique is the necessity of using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the input array so that the compiler infers the string elements in the array as literals:

```ts
const requiredEnvVars = ["SECRET_1", "SECRET_2"] as const;
//                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

Failing to do so will prevent the compiler from being able to infer the key literals, causing a return type that has no entries:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-P5reEK6AhiJcUEwUiESDJMNkQKprgs5rHDNlRPpSiZbJ5FK9Dr0ADKOQAwgccgAVAD6AEZ6NdGy2212AEz0LrBpnsYAAPV2abAAHkDmM00WQYMm62Oz3ZhvB9vh7vQJuh52AMyzRHljJZXL5OsDrdd3v9k8HscToA)

```ts
const secrets = validateEnv(["SECRET_1", "SECRET_2"]);
    //^? const secrets: Record<never, never>
```

On the bright side: the release of TypeScript 5.0 is just around the corner, and the new [`const` type parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#const-type-parameters) feature will allow you to influence the inference behavior, making it unnecessary to use the const assertion on the argument value:

[TS Playground (using nightly compiler)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=5.0.0-dev.20230210#code/PQgEB4CcFMDNpgOwMbVIg9gWgCZwIYCuANgC5bECWARgLwBEpkh09owAfAFAjAQzwkqUFTr1oAZ0TQAHqTaceYKHATQUaUgE8ADpIaY8C7mAACpCVkoBzTDC6UAtjoyRSoeud2Tgh1gG4uWRc3UABvAF9ArlhCFFJKDERQADd8Khx8UmgAUUQU8GQkiXcAaWgtCVBZbMQcKph8HCTiLVASyEpEawBtAF0OAAouUFAAawqJAC5QcsqAGi4AShmOrt6+6rl1etnJ0AB+UAAlaCLIHHBpFIR59GgbyA5QGdPzy7mJHsRCR2oEPp3NbdZ5hEagIqIEqgGASEjuWjhCKgfBVN6uD6Tb6-f6QQHtJjrDjRUawVygQaQ6ETNoYWDjSZLcLg0ZU9xpYgsUCInSQDCoCQSAB06hSPRpfUCo1GlHpgwAhByWEzSAALPkAd3uWpykD5kEGAAMcjI9MhsjhqvlKHzEI51Oz8J18NRiGh6AASMI0iJsTDuCTQUiGpZS6Ww+HiiooqqfbF-AGbRFK6BhiJccEwUiESDJCNkQLprhs9pnLNVZPpSiZbJ5FKDHr0ADKOQAwsccgAVAD6AEZ6Hdm22Oz2AEz0PqhlnsYAAPQOGbAAHljlMMyWwaMW+2u33FqMQPPwduR93R-uZ0et8PdwBmO7AABUoF1+opqK2ZotS3BAD9-wB-7ggACnyehuG0ADkJ53pBoDNJI6AYO4siUNCSSgNoeigJB6IXOAQ47j2-agAAPh4MFjgOBKdCCkFCoMo63reACcTKPsAXDIpWGRZLk+QNoRp79oOlFnhOU5AA)

```ts
// Same implementation as above
declare function validateEnv<const Keys extends readonly string[]>(
//                           ^^^^^
  keys: Keys,
): string[] extends Keys ? Record<never, never> : Record<Keys[number], string>;

const secrets = validateEnv(["SECRET_1", "SECRET_2"]);
    //^? const secrets: Record<"SECRET_1" | "SECRET_2", string>

// OR:

const {
  SECRET_1,
  //^? const SECRET_1: string
  SECRET_2,
  //^? const SECRET_2: string
  SECRET_3, /* Error (as expected)
  ~~~~~~~~
  Property 'SECRET_3' does not exist on type 'Record<"SECRET_1" | "SECRET_2", string>'.(2339) */
} = validateEnv(["SECRET_1", "SECRET_2"]);
```